# iPod Touch to iPod Touch Messaging using Push Notification Service

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipod-touch, ipod

Can I use the push notification to send the message from one iPod touch to another one? Is there any pointer information that I can read?

Thank you!
Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it's non-trivial. You can use [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/) to send the notifications, but you'll still need some kind of intermediary server to actually figure out how to get two people each other's device tokens for sending.